# Inserting whole sql script in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have problem inserting sql script in the variable.I have this code

```
   declare @result_var varchar(max);
SET @result_var=''; 
DECLARE @cursor CURSOR, 
@name   VARCHAR(100) 
SET @cursor = CURSOR 
FOR SELECT [NAME] 
    FROM   [iflvs08].mds.mdm.lv_budget_employee
OPEN @cursor
FETCH next FROM @cursor INTO @name 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 
      IF (RIGHT(@Name, 1) = ' ')
        begin
            IF( Len(@result_var) > 1 ) 
              SET @result_var=@result_var + ','+ @name 
            ELSE 
              SET @result_var=@name 
        END
      FETCH next FROM @cursor INTO @name 
  END
```

I want to insert into variable it but when try to insert it like this

```
set @sql='code here'
```

It get confuse whit this ' symbol and dont insert it 
I always get error like this
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near '
        begin
            IF( Len(@result_var) > 1 ) 
              SET @result_var=@result_var + '.

Comment: There are better ways than using cursors for concatenating values from several rows into a comma-separated list; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string.

Comment: What are you really trying to do here? Cursors are very poor performance wise and should be used only in certain situations. Data manipulation is not one of those times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically you have to replace all `'` symbols with `''`

```
set @sql = '

  declare @result_var varchar(max);
SET @result_var=''''; 
DECLARE @cursor CURSOR, 
@name   VARCHAR(100) 
SET @cursor = CURSOR 
FOR SELECT [NAME] 
    FROM   [iflvs08].mds.mdm.lv_budget_employee
OPEN @cursor
FETCH next FROM @cursor INTO @name 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 
      IF (RIGHT(@Name, 1) = '' '')
        begin
            IF( Len(@result_var) > 1 ) 
              SET @result_var=@result_var + '',''+ @name 
            ELSE 
              SET @result_var=@name 
        END
      FETCH next FROM @cursor INTO @name 
  END'
```

Comment: Thx it was so simple :)